# (h2o.ai python) h2o.init() Cannot import name flow

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to run h2o for python (version 2.7.13) and am getting this error when trying to use `h2o.init()` (or `h2o.h2o.init()`).

```
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321. connected.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-a1412a2642a8> in <module>()
      2 
      3 # http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3135/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html#h2o.h2o.init
----> 4 h2o.h2o.init(start_h2o=True)

/cygdrive/c/Users/rvillanueva/python-virtualenvs-base/h2o-model-retraining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/h2o.pyc in init(url, ip, port, https, insecure, username, password, cookies, proxy, start_h2o, nthreads, ice_root, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, strict_version_check, ignore_config, **kwargs)
    256         hs = H2OLocalServer.start(nthreads=nthreads, enable_assertions=enable_assertions, max_mem_size=mmax,
    257                                   min_mem_size=mmin, ice_root=ice_root, port=port)
--> 258         h2oconn = H2OConnection.open(server=hs, https=https, verify_ssl_certificates=not insecure,
    259                                      auth=auth, proxy=proxy,cookies=cookies, verbose=True)
    260     if check_version:

/cygdrive/c/Users/rvillanueva/python-virtualenvs-base/h2o-model-retraining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/h2o.pyc in version_check()
    108     return h2oconn
    109 
--> 110 
    111 def version_check():
    112     """Used to verify that h2o-python module and the H2O server are compatible with each other."""

/cygdrive/c/Users/rvillanueva/python-virtualenvs-base/h2o-model-retraining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/__init__.py in <module>()
      9 from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
     10 
---> 11 from h2o.h2o import (connect, init, api, connection,
     12                      lazy_import, upload_file, import_file, import_sql_table, import_sql_select,
     13                      parse_setup, parse_raw, assign, deep_copy, get_model, get_grid, get_frame,

ImportError: cannot import name flow
```

I am doing this in jupyter notebook, but I get this same error when I run

```
>>import h2o
>>h2o.init()
```

from the console. Using `h2o.h2o.H2OConnection.jar_paths()` shows that my h2o.jar file is in the path and I have made sure that the h2o.jar version and python h2o package version are the same (and latest 3.10.5.4)), so I am not sure what could be going wrong here.

Running `h2o.cluster().show_status()` after trying to init() h2o gives the output:

```
H2O cluster uptime: 16 mins 56 secs
H2O cluster version:    3.10.5.4
H2O cluster version age:    23 days
H2O cluster name:   ******
H2O cluster total nodes:    2
H2O cluster free memory:    7.028 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    16
H2O cluster allowed cores:  16
H2O cluster status: accepting new members, 1 nodes are not healthy
H2O connection url: http://localhost:54321
H2O connection proxy:   None
H2O internal security:  False
Python version: 2.7.13 final
```

Which makes me think that the init() worked (at least partially), but the error makes me wonder what problems are going to sneak up down the road.

Help about what this means and how to resolve it would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same problem except that it works when I run it from the console. I'm using h2o 3.15